# Get properties of property in C#

Tags: c#, excel, system.reflection

I am trying to check if my object "chartObject" has the property "Chart", and if the property "Chart" has the sub-property "ChartArea". I know both statements are true.

I have the following code:

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor p1 in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(chartObject))
{
    if (p1.Name == "Chart")
    {
        currentSheet.Range["D2"].Value = true; //Prints TRUE in cell D2 as expected

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor p2 in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(p1))
        {
            if ( p2.Name == "ChartArea")
            {
                currentSheet.Range["D3"].Value = true; //Doesn't print anything in D3, why?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**When I print p2.Name it returns "DesignTimeOnly"**, which is not a property of `chartObject.Chart.`, so this is probably where the problem lies. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Feel free to solve the problem in another way than I've tried above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you are invoking `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(p1)` in the nested foreach loop you are getting the properties of the object p1, which is from type `PropertyDescriptor` and not from the the actual Chart property type and `DesignTimeOnly` is exactly one of the properties of the `PropertyDescriptor`.

To get the properties that you actually need you have call `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties()` passing the actual `chartObject.Chart` property.

Comment: Aaah of course. This has been driving me crazy for hours. It works now. Thank you.